# FOSElasticaBundle and FPNTagBudle index tags

Tags: symfony, tags, foselasticabundle

I am using `FPNTagBudle` for tagging my documents and `FOSElasticaBundle` for indexing them into elasticsearch index.

With `FPNTagBudle` to load tags into object you need to use `loadTagging` method like so:

```
$tagManager = $this->get('fpn_tag.tag_manager');
$tagManager->loadTagging($object);
```

When a object is edited from form, I have tags loaded so everything works fine and when object is saved index is build up properly. The problem is when I run `fos:elastica:populate` command to populate all object the tagging is skipped, becasue tagging is not loaded then.

I tried to hook to `PRE_TRANSFORM` event and loadTagging there but then it messes with the form, because new tags added from the form are wiped by calling `loadTagging` the second time.

Is it possible to recognize in `PRE_TRANSFORM` hook that this is populate command so I could loadTagging only then? Or maybe my problem is more fundamental?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with `PRE_TRANSFORM` event and distinguishing whether it comes from form or populate command with `php_sapi_name()`. Below whole solution:

**Subscriber**:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Event\TransformEvent;
use FPN\TagBundle\Entity\TagManager;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Class ElasticaTransformSubscriber
 * @package AppBundle\EventSubscriber
 */
class ElasticaTransformSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /** @var TagManager */
    private $tagManager;

    /**
     * ElasticaTransformSubscriber constructor.
     * @param $tagManager
     */
    public function __construct(TagManager $tagManager)
    {
        $this->tagManager = $tagManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param TransformEvent $event
     */
    public function preTransformOperations(TransformEvent $event)
    {
        if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
            $object = $event->getObject();
            $this->tagManager->loadTagging($object);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            TransformEvent::PRE_TRANSFORM => 'preTransformOperations',
        );
    }
}
```

**Service**:

```
app.subscriber.object_transformer_elastica:
    class: AppBundle\EventSubscriber\ElasticaTransformSubscriber
    arguments: ["@fpn_tag.tag_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```